# SBT console missing web container's classpath

Tags: sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

Using SBT with [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin), when I go to the console (`sbt console`), I can't access anything in `src/main/webapp` that is normally on the containers classpath.

Context is: I'm trying to take certain code that runs in both the webapp and unit tests, and run it in  the console. Everything is fine until I reach code that loads one of the view templates stored in `src/main/webapp`, which it expects to find on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of *webapp* are generally not included on the classpath in deployment (i.e. under standard J2EE containers such as Tomcat, Jetty, etc.), so you might want to move your resources somewhere more conventional, such as *src/main/resources* which is included on both the runtime and the container classpath.

[Here](https://github.com/earldouglas/mustache.scala) is an example xsbt-web-plugin project that uses Mustache templates that are stored under *src/main/resources* and thus included on the classpath.